# Ionic Google maps Can not find the element [#map_canvas]

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic4

I have a Ionic App using google maps polyline to get latitude and longitude from data json api for flight route . l want to do reload data automatic , to see live data on map . l added set Interval to reload data. The data is reload and console , but l have error below and no live data showing on map .

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Can not find the element [#map_canvas]
Error: Can not find the element [#map_canvas]
    at vendor.js:76400
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.js:2781)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js:51333)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.js:2780)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (polyfills.js:2553)
    at push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask (polyfills.js:2856)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (polyfills.js:2845)
    at timer (polyfills.js:4639)
    at resolvePromise (polyfills.js:3189)
    at resolvePromise (polyfills.js:3146)
    at polyfills.js:3250
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.js:2781)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js:51333)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.js:2780)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (polyfills.js:2553)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (polyfills.js:2959)
    at push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask (polyfills.js:2860)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (polyfills.js:2845)
```

my code

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.platform.ready();
    this.getmarker();

setInterval(()=> {
  this.getmarker()
},4000); 

  }

  async getmarker() {
    this.http.get('xxxxxxx.json?flightId=4232343, {}, {})

      .then(data => {

        for (let datas of JSON.parse(data.data).result.response.data.flight['track']) {
          this.points.push({ lng: datas.longitude, lat: datas.latitude });
        }
        let AIR_PORTS = this.points;
        console.log(AIR_PORTS)

        this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas', {
          camera: {
            target: AIR_PORTS
          }
        });

        let polyline: Polyline = this.map.addPolylineSync({
          points: AIR_PORTS,
          color: '#AA00FF',
          width: 5,
          geodesic: true,
          clickable: true,


        });

        let points: Array<ILatLng> = this.points = []



      })
  }
```

html

```
  <div style="height: 100%;width: 100%" id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Are you doing it in a modal? According to (this)[https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native-google-maps/issues/172], it does not work on modal.

Comment: Try remove background color to ion-content, this working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show the entire html? please make sure that the parent element has some height. **CSS always treats percent values as a percentage of the parent element.**

Oftentimes this problem is caused by 0px height being allocated. Think of it in this way, the map div was empty on init, the parent element would have 0px height. When we fill in the map stuff later, we will not see anything because the height 100% of the parent 0px is 0px.

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-card style="height: 50%">
        <div style="height: 100%;width: 100%" id="map_canvas"></div>
    </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Make sure the parent element (i.e. ion-card in the above example) has some height on init. You can set a fixed height for testing and it will prove my point.

```
<div style="height: 200px;" id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Good luck.